# Double indexed sequence's almost sure convergence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose there is a sequence $a_{n,m}$ such that $a_{n,m}->a_n$ as m goes infinity, for all n, and $a_{n,m}->0$ almost surely for all m. Then, does $\lim_{m->\infty}a_{n,m}=a_n$ converges almost surely to zero when n goes infinity?

I first tried usung triangle inequality, however, taking limit in this case seems bit subtle to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_{nm}=1$ for $n <m$ and $a_{nm}=0$ for $n \geq m$. The the hypothesis is satisfied and $a_n \to 1$.

Comment: Oh thank you. Do you know what if $a_n:=sup_{m\in N}a_{n,m}$?